# Picking out every number and adding it into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i have some text here

```
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 131046468 | |
```

I want it to get every number after "UserID" and place it into an array, with Javascript
How would I do such a thing?

Comment: There are a few ways. Have you tried any yourself? Have you ever heard of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that sorry

Comment: Then read some of the examples. Try a few things out. You have to experiment with ideas. No one is going to write your code for you.

Comment: That's why @MikeC provided a link to the docs, so you could learn.  ;)

Comment: You'll also want to consider how the text is getting into Javascript in the first place. Are you reading it from a file? Some of the possible answers are going to depend on how the text is being stored - a single string? An array of strings?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.  It's a community built around respect and helping others _who demonstrate effort_.  You've done neither.  Comment flagged, voting to close.

Comment: @S i've just tried this var x = s.split("UserID: ")[1].replace(" | || | Serial: N/A | | ", "132382474 | || | Serial: N/A | | ","");
console.log(x);

Comment: ~@above comment  it didnt work unfortunately :( And it's a single string yes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can extract these numbers using [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), but you'll have to use `g` flag since you'll be extracting multiple numbers, and `String.prototype.match()` fails with global search (if you're planning to use capture). You can use a custom match function:

```js
var text = "| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 131046468 | |";

function match(string, regex) {
  var matches = [];
  var match = null;
  while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
  }
  return matches;
}

var numbers = match(text, /UserID:\s(\d*)?/g);

console.log(numbers);
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
            capture only the numbers -> 132382474
           /-\
/UserID:\s(\d*)?/g      g -> global search, search multiple times
\______________/
        |
search this pattern ->  UserID: 132382474
```

---

It's necessary that you pass the pattern with `g` flag, otherwise `while` will create an infinite loop.

Or just make sure the pattern has a `g` flag using another function. This way, you can pass the pattern without the `g` flag. `global()` function will check the pattern. If it's missing the `g` flag, it'll add it automatically.

```js
var text = "| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 131046468 | |";

function match(string, regex) {
  var regex = global(regex);
  var matches = [];
  var match = null;
  while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
  }
  return matches;
}

function global(re) {
  var pattern = re.source;
  var flags = re.global ? re.flags : re.flags += "g";
  return new RegExp(pattern, flags);
}

var numbers = match(text, /UserID:\s(\d*)?/);

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: Can the downvoter care to explain what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

What you've got looks a bit like pipe-delimited data. Not sure exactly what you're doing, but I'm going to assume the following things:

- You will sometimes have something between those `| |`s
- You want all the data coming in, not just the `UserID`s
- This isn't a node-stream or some other stream, but just a big 'ol gob of text. If it were, you'd have to break it out by line as you went...

So here goes...

```js
var someText = 
  "| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\n"
  +"| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\n"
  +"| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\n"
  +"| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 131046468 | |";

var lines = someText.split('\n'); //Break apart by line
var data = lines.map(function(line) {
  var entries = line.split('|'); //Break apart by pipe
  var output = {};
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    var keyValue = entry.split(':'); //Break apart by colon
    if (!keyValue[1]) {
      return; //We don't have something in the form of 'key: value'
    }
    var key = keyValue[0].trim(); //This will get rid of unwanted whitespace
    var value = keyValue[1].trim();
    output[key] = value;
  });
  return output;
});

console.log(data);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is returning an array with a single object containing the last id.

Comment: @akinuri, I have updated it with sample data. It runs now.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a global match, use this:

`text.match(/\d+/g)`

given:

```
var text = "| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 132382474 | |\
| | Serial: N/A | | UserID: 131046468 | |";
```